# C# question about line graphics and screen size

Tags: c#, graphics, line

I just started playing around with graphics today and did a quick test to see if things line up as expected, they do not.

If I use this.Width = 818; and this.Height = 642; the lines look as expected.

I must be missing something simple here.

Added a picture.

[image: something off here]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Width = 800;
            this.Height = 600;
        }
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.White);
            Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            g.DrawLine(myPen, 800, 0, 0, 600);
            g.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 800, 600);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The height and width of the form includes the title bar and any borders it has, therefore the paintable user area will always be something smaller than that.

Comment: How do you launch a paintable window with dimensions that match what you entered?

Comment: In WPF you can create windows that size to fit their content, but I don't think that's possible in WinForms. As far as I know, your only option is to figure out what the extra border values are and add those to the size of your content area, similar to what you did in your example code.